# Strip Header When Outputting Variables

Tags: html, powershell, csv

Based on another question I posted on here, I was able to get the majority of this script working, but I don't know how to change the formatting of a select-object. Google has been no help.

```
$head = @'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Current Conditions</title>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <h3 style="margin:0;padding-bottom:3px">Current Conditions at 
'@

$1 = @'
</h3>
    <p style="margin:0;padding-bottom:0px"><b>Dewpoint: </b>
'@

$2 = @'
</p>
    <p style="margin:0;padding-bottom:0px"><b>Temperature: </b>
'@

$3 = @'
</p>
    <p style="margin:0;padding-bottom:3px"><b>Humidity: </b>
'@

$end = @'
</p>
    </body>
</html>
'@

$info = import-csv 1-pastweek.csv
$time = $info | select -last 1 Time
$temp = $info | select -last 1 Temp
$humid = $info | select -last 1 Humid
$dewpt = $info | select -last 1 Dewpt

$head + $time + $1 + $dewpt + $2 + $temp + $3 + $humid + $end | out-file -encoding "UTF8" current.html
```

This does work, but the format of the html output includes the header info from the CSV and I don't see how to get around it.

```
Current Conditions at @{TIME=03/12/2012 15:32:22}

Dewpoint: @{DEWPT=62.7}

Temperature: @{TEMP=71.9}

Humidity: @{HUMID=74.4}
```

Any ideas on how to get the @{HEADER } to go away. I only want the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you were trying, you just had to add `-expandproperty` to get the actual value rather than objects with the property.

For example:

```
$time = $info | select -last 1 -expand Time
```

and you can use `$time` directly, rather than `$time.TIME`

Also, if this is all you are doing and you are going to use the `$time.TIME` etc. you could have done:

```
$info = import-csv 1-pastweek.cs | select -last 1
```

and used `$info.Time` etc.

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually did find the expandproperty, but did not use it correctly. Also, I like your last bit. That will be the way I do it. That is easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have posted is correct, what code are you using to combine these strings?

It looks like you may be doing the following:

```
$head + $time + $1 + $dewpt + $2 + $temp + $3 + $humid + $end
```

When you want to specify a part of the intermediate objects like so:

```
$head + $time.TIME + $1 + $dewpt.DEWPT + $2 + $temp.TEMP + $3 + $humid.HUMID + $end
```

This syntax assumes that you are using hashtables (`@{}`) to hold your objects.

Comment: Well... that was the simplest fix that I have seen. (I feel like a bit of a moron.) But, thanks a bunch for your help.